# Simplify rundeck cluster

Tags: mariadb, cluster-computing, rundeck

I've try to setup the simplify cluster for rundeck solution , the simplify mean no need for automatic failover , but the data protection and consistency is the main focus.

The system architecture will be

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQQ3k.png)

I'm not sure , is the architecture as I've designed is possible for rundeck community version or not .

The purpose of the architecture is the data protection , some downtime accept with manual failover. The database is MariaDB , any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use Rundeck on Cluster environments is through Rundeck Enterprise (with Autotakeover, Remote Job Execution, and Replication capacities out of the box), you can check the architecture [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/cluster/#rundeck-enterprise-architecture). Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/enterprise/#high-availability), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WWxxUOIFVw) video and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yYwTPMRSOY) is useful to see how to works.